# Regex to remove everything after the second dot in a number

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find a regex for removing everything after the the second dot in a number e.g `12.23.45.45` to become `12.23.`
Thanks

Comment: You can easily do this using `strpos` and `substr`. Or even with `explode`. Does it have to be a regular expression?

Comment: you could simple use: `/\d+.\d+.` to get everything up to the second dot.. but you could also use something like `substr` ...

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
^(\d+\.\d+\.)
```

The result you want is in group 1.

Comment: This is showing the last digits `234.22` instead of `12.23`

Comment: Thanks alot @toto, tried with `re.sub("^(\d+\.\d+\.)", "", "12.23.234.22")` but the result is still `234.22`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern and then replace the first capture group with an empty string:

```
\..*?\.(.+)
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dH7zH5/1)

Comment: Using python regex substitute `re.sub("\..*?\.(.+)", "", "12.23.234.22")` , the output is 12